# Returning a 404 results in: XML Parsing Error: no element found

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-4.0

I have the following in the codebehind of a page:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 404;
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

But I get (In the browser. Visual Web Developer doesn't throw any exception):

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://localhost:...
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

I tried putting those lines in the `MasterPage` but it didn't make a difference. 
I even tried putting them in a `PreRenderComplete` event handler.

So why is it showing that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried uploading it to my web-host, and it returned a normal 404.

So it seems it's different in Visual Web Developer. (Or perhaps it depends on the host, and will not always be OK?)

Answer (score -1):

The response object lets you write to the HttpResponse directly.  In your example you're clearing it.  Replacing it with the status 404 and ending.  This means anything which the framework has added for you (like the page content) has been removed.

Can't just configure a 404 page in IIS?

Comment: But won't the 404 cause the browser to show a 404 kind of message? (It does if I try some completely nonexistent page.)